# Cannot SSH to my Server, The connection Hangs

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, macos, remote-access

Hello i have setup a home server which I am trying to access remotly. I did this a while back and untill recently I moved homes and ISP. I have port forwarded with my new ISP to be able to access the Server for remote access but the connection hangs everytime and I am not recieving the expected output on the console where I have logged in to the server. Using verbose i get the following:

```
McBookPro:~ MSRAHMAN$ ssh -vvv msrahman@elizaweb.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/MSRAHMAN/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to elizaweb.com [86.6.215.211] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/MSRAHMAN/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/MSRAHMAN/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/MSRAHMAN/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/MSRAHMAN/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
```

Please can someone help me, I am new to this stuff and I don't understand why it is not working when it worked perfectly fine before I moved. Is there something I am missing. Also I am unable to physically access the server as I am a few hundred miles away right now which is why I want to remote access.

Comment: Can you pull up your /var/log/syslog and /var/log/auth.log from the server?

Comment: I cannot access the server so to your question No i can not.

Comment: Do you know what version of what distro the server's running? You might have success if you try ssh using the same distro & version elsewhere.

Comment: try `telnet your_server 22`. I'm not sure You are getting TCP connection at all (maybe machine is off, forwarding incorrect, wrong IP and so on).

Comment: @kestasx: Sorry, but TCP connection is correctly established, as for what clearly reported at row 9 above (debug1: Connection established.)

Comment: @MSRahman: have you tried to wait a **LONG** time (something like 30/60/90 seconds)? If not, please wait at least 120 seconds and report us if something change.

Comment: I tried waiting but nothing happens, it is not even asking me for a password?

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli, true, but are You sure it is expected machine (raw output should print machine name)?

Comment: Yes I am 100%. I have also remotely accessed the machine the network is connected to and checked if the machine is running, which it is. I have given the machine a static IP am I correct to say is that all that needs to be done to access the machine now is port forwarding on my router and that should work?

Comment: @MSRahman what do You mean **accessed the machine the network is connected to** (what exactly You did)? How did You check machine is running (ping? arping?)?

Comment: I logged into the ISP router and checked for connected devices. Then did a Ping from there.

Comment: @MSRahman, You have set static IP on machine. Did You set gateway (and checked the machine can acces internet)? You logged into ISP router via http/https or ssh? Has ISP router any firewall logs?